# I need to add security headers in my next js application

Tags: security, next.js, frontend, response-headers

I have a next js application and i need to add security headers in the next.config.js file

This is my current code

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const semi = require("@douyinfe/semi-next").default({})
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = semi({
output: "export",
assetPrefix: ".",
transpilePackages: [
"@douyinfe/semi-ui",
"@douyinfe/semi-icons",
"@douyinfe/semi-illustrations",
],
typescript: {
 ignoreBuildErrors: true
},
eslint: {
ignoreDuringBuilds: true
}
})

module.exports = nextConfig
```

And i need to add this

```js
async headers() {
  return [
    {
      source: "/(.*)?",
      headers: [
        {
          key: "X-Frame-Options",
          value: "DENY",
        },
        {
          key: "X-Content-Type-Options",
          value: "nosniff",
        },
        {
          key: "Referrer-Policy",
          value: "origin-when-cross-origin",
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
},
```

but if i add this in my code, it throws error,
i get this error - "the headers property cannot be used when the output option is set to "export"."

If i remove the output:"export" option, it works but I cannot remove the output:"export" option because it is important for my application.
Please suggest a way to add headers in my application

Comment: Do you use export to generate a static website? Then I think that headers can't be sent because it's only static content that is server. Can you add the headers on your web hosting?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution

Comment: Please explain what steps you perform to get the error: do you run a command? What is that command? What is the environment: local on your computer, on an online hosting service, etc.?

Comment: the environment is local and i run "yarn dev " command

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware to add headers to your request, use this sample code in your middleware.js:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
 
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
// Clone the request headers and set a new header `x-hello-from- 
middleware1`
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
  requestHeaders.set('x-hello-from-middleware1', 'hello')

  // You can also set request headers in NextResponse.rewrite
  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      // New request headers
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  })

  // Set a new response header `x-hello-from-middleware2`
  response.headers.set('x-hello-from-middleware2', 'hello')
  return response
}
```

Checkout the documentation:

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware#setting-headers

Comment: the middlewares are also not supported when the output:"export" is set, this doesn't work